No sound problem on Ubuntu 22.04 on a Huawei MateBook D16 laptop
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Huawei MateBook D16 laptop. There is no sound from the laptop.
Results of alsamixer :


The only way to solve this problem is to install ubuntu version 24.04, everything works without problems. i tried it and it works fine without problem.
Users are experiencing bugs while upgrading from 22.04. It is recommended that you back up your files and fresh install 24.04.
